# Mac OS - Change Status Item Button Image

Tags: swift, image, macos, nsstatusitem

I want to update the image when the user clicks something in the application but I can't get it to work.
The status item with the menu is defined in the AppDelegate. I am trying to update the image in the ViewController with this piece of code which I think should work:

```
AppDelegate().statusItem.button?.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("icon-orange"))
```

No errors are showing up, but turns out it still doesn't work, so is it possible to change the image or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AppDelegate()` creates a brand new instance which is **not** the delegate class in Interface Builder.

You need the real reference:

```
(NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate).statusItem.button?.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("icon-orange"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect! Pretty new to swift so maybe it was a dumb question ;)

Comment: No, it's not. I wish the compiler would show a warning if a class which is designed in Interface Builder is going to be initialized with the default initializer `...()`

Comment: Is this also possible for getting an already defined class? For example if you have the ViewController class and a Settings class. A variable is defined in the ViewController. Then you want to update from the Settings class the variable in the ViewController class. You don't want to create a new instance, right? So, maybe there is something similar to the solution to get the real delegate?

Comment: Yes, for classes designed in IB you need always the actual reference.

Comment: Do you maybe have a small code example of getting the actual reference of an already defined class? Can't find it with a quick Google search...

Comment: Sorry that's beyond the scope of this question. Please ask a new one.